# ADODB.Connection in vba: operation not allowed when object is closed

Tags: vba, excel, ado

I am finalizing a vba macro, and wonder if someone could assist with the following error message:

```
run-time error '3704'
operation is not allowed when the object is closed
```

Code:

================================

```
Sub upload()
'
' upload Macro
'
Dim adoCN As ADODB.Connection
Dim sConnString As String
Dim sSQL As String
Dim lRow As Long
Dim i As Integer

sConnString = "Provider=sqloledb;Server=xxx;User Id=xxx;Password=xxx"
Set adoCN = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Sheets("sql").Activate
Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown)).Select
lRow = Selection.Rows.Count
For i = 2 To lRow
sSQL = "INSERT INTO tblData (ISN, Date, Px_last) " & _
        " VALUES (" & _
        "'" & Cells(i, 1) & "', " & _
        "'" & Cells(i, 2) & "', " & _
        "'" & Cells(i, 3) & "')"
adoCN.Execute sSQL
Next i
adoCN.Close
Set adoCN = Nothing
End Sub
```

Best,

Comment: What line does the error happen on?

Comment: @MatthewD: at `adoCN.Execute sSQL`. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You need to open the connection before you can use it.

```
sConnString = "Provider=sqloledb;Server=xxx;User Id=xxx;Password=xxx"
Set adoCN = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
adoCN.Open
```

Comment: cheers. i now end up with `[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] data source name not found and no default driver specified`. Do i need to update in `sConnString` the provider from `sqloledb` to `odbc`? thx

Comment: Yeah, you will need to get your connection string built correctly.  What are you connecting to? Access, Oracle, etc.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18313899/vba-new-database-connection  Looks like the format is sConnString = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=; Database=; UID=; PWD="  Fill in the blanks with your server, database, uid and pwd

Comment: Look here for more info on the connection params.  http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/617788-visual-basic-applications-connect-sql-server.html

Comment: same odbc error with suggested `sConnString = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=; Database=; UID=; PWD="`. will do more research on vba-odbc, as in matlab i am usually setting up easly my connexion string with `conn = database('odbcname', 'UID', 'PWD')`. cheers.