# run query from different database on separate server connected via ODBC

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I'm using Access 2010. Right now I have a function called SetQuerySource:

```
Private Sub SetQuerySource()
Dim sql As String

sql = DLookup("QueryText", "tblQuery", "QueryName ='qselDailyMilkYield'")
CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qselDailyMilkYield").sql = sql
sql = sql & vbCrLf & "where pt.DLVDate between '" & Me.txtDate 
& "' AND '" & Me.txtEndDate & "' and pb.ITEMID like '%pm%' and pjb.ITEMID 
like '%pm%' group by pt.ITEMID, pb.ITEMID, pt.NAME, pt.DLVDATE"
CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qselDailyMilkYield").sql = sql
End Sub
```

I use this to run a query located in a table named tblQuery in my Access database. I then append the Where clause to the query using VBA in case (as shown above) I need to point to a named control which holds a value based on user input.

I came into this setup. By that I mean I didn't create this function I just began using it. My question is how do I point to a different database on a different server? The query I need to run has tables (connected via ODBC) already linked to this Access database but my search of OpenDatabase proved futile as I didn't understand how to use it in my environment.

I receive this error:

> [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'dbo.MilkReceived'. (#208)

```
Private Sub cmdTruckDeliveries_Click()

SetQuerySource
DoCmd.OpenReport "rptTruckDeliveries", acViewPreview
End Sub
```

This is my code for the button click event jic.

Thank you,

Comment: Review http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18313899/vba-new-database-connection.

Comment: Thank you. Still having trouble after reviewing.