# Macro to Get Data from Iseries (AS400) using Excel VBA

Tags: vba, ibm-midrange

I am getting data from AS400 via Excel add-in and I'm trying to find an automated to do this because I have to do this many times with various source files and it's annoying to constantly to having to log in whenever I use a new source file.

For instance, for the source file "bond.tto" I would do this to download it:

In Excel, 
go to "Add-Ins" --> "Transfer Data from iSeries." A "Transfer Request" window pops up and from there I choose "create a new file"... the path and the file name is c:\bond.tto.

"starting cell position" I chose column A and row 1 and click "include column headings."  I press "OK."

then I enter my credentials which let's say my user name is "abc" and pw is "abc."  The server...let's call it "BLUE.TOR.MCFLY.COM."

Could somebody suggest code to automate this?  Please and thank you.

The macro recorder doesn't give me any lines of code to work with.
No errors as the macro recorder doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

As a side note, you can also use open JT400 in `java` to use DB2 SQL to query your tables.

Using VBA you can also use queries as follows:

The code I am using here is primarily from [VBA New Database Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18313899/vba-new-database-connection).

However, of importance to you is your database connection string.
This is using the Client Access ODBC driver to connect to an IBM i DB2 database on a server with the name POWER7 and other options. The "translate" option I believe takes it from the 65535 CSSID and converts it to something nice from EBDIC.

```
Sub DbConnection()

    Dim cn As Object ' ADODB.Connection
    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") ' New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As Object ' ADODB.Recordset

    Dim strConn As String
    strConn = "DRIVER={Client Access ODBC Driver (32-bit)};" & _
                "Database=<myDataBase>;" & _
                "Hostname=<POWER7>;" & _
                "Port=1234;" & _
                "Protocol=TCPIP;" & _
                "Uid=<USERID>;" & _
                "Pwd=<PASSWORD>;" & _
                "SYSTEM=<POWER7>;" & _
                "DBQ=QGPL <YOUR BASE LIBRARY> <ANOTHER>;" & _
                "DFTPKGLIB=QGPL;" & _
                "LANGUAGEID=ENU;" & _
                "PKG=QGPL/DEFAULT(IBM),2,0,1,0,512;QRYSTGLMT=-1;" & _
                "TRANSLATE=1;" & _
                "CONNTYPE=2;" & _
                "REGIONAL=NO;"

    cn.Open strConn

    Dim queryArr, i
    queryArr = Array("SELECT * FROM <LIBRARY>.<TABLE>")

    For i = LBound(queryArr) To UBound(queryArr)
        ExecuteQuery queryArr(i), cn, rs
    Next i

    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub ExecuteQuery(query As Variant, ByRef cn As Object, ByRef rs As Object)
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset") ' New ADODB.Recordset
    With rs
        .ActiveConnection = cn
        .Open CStr(query)
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs
        .Close
    End With
    Set rs = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: The Database, Hostname, and SYSTEM parameters, as well as the DBQ parameter for which base libraries you want to use...

Answer (score 0):

test this:

```
 Option Explicit
    Option Base 1

    Sub Firmennamen()
    On Error GoTo ERRORHANDLER

    Dim sSQLFirmen As String
    Dim objListObj As ListObject
    Dim objListCols As ListColumns
    Set WB = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws_Einstellungen = WB.Worksheets("Einstellung") ' tab name in excel
    Set objListObj = ws_Einstellungen.ListObjects("FirmenNamen") ' table name in excel
    Set objListCols = objListObj.ListColumns

        ws_Einstellungen.Range("FirmenNamen").ClearContents ' clear table

        sconnect = "PROVIDER=IBMDA400;Data Source=server_name;USER ID=username;PASSWORD=Password;"
        conn.ConnectionTimeout = 30
        conn.Open sconnect
        Set mrs.ActiveConnection = conn
        sSQLFirmen = " SELECT t.col1 AS Nr, t.col2 AS Firma " & _
                    " From server_name.schema_name.table_name t " & _
                    " WHERE t.col2='010' " & _
                    " ORDER BY t.col1 "
        mrs.Open sSQLFirmen, conn
        For i = 0 To mrs.fields.count - 1
                    objListCols(i + 1).Name = mrs.fields(i).Name
                Next i
        ws_Einstellungen.Range("FirmenNamen").CopyFromRecordset mrs
        mrs.Close
        conn.Close
        Set mrs = Nothing
        Set conn = Nothing
        Exit Sub
         'get out before the Error Handler kicks in

        '//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        ERRORHANDLER:
            Call ERROR
        End

        End Sub





        Private Sub Workbook_Open()
            Call Firmennamen ' when excel open --> query update
        End Sub




        Sub ERROR()

            Select Case Err.Number
                Case -2147217843
                    msg = "Sie müssen Ihre User ID und Password eintragen: " & Err.Number _
                    & " oder Ihre user ID und Password sind nicht correct."
                    MsgBox msg, vbOKOnly
                Case 13
                    msg = "You have text data in a numeric field (" & BadField & "). Fix and re-Upload"
                    MsgBox msg, vbOKOnly
                Case 1004
                    msg = "Firma fehlt oder ist ungültig !"
                    MsgBox msg, vbOKOnly

                Case Else
                    msg = "DIe Fehler ist: " & Err.Number & " /  " & Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & " Bitte sich bei IT melden (mit Screenshot dieser Meldung) !! :(  "
                    MsgBox msg, vbOKOnly
            End Select

            Err.Clear
            'Set GetConnection = Nothing

        End Sub
```